# Attempt to reference null exception

Tags: apex, class, visualforce, boolean

I am getting the above error at below line. Can someone Please let me know? It should be true or false , why null?

**Apex class**

```
   List<Account>  Accnt= [select ID , Name , Restricted_Products_vod__c from Account where ID=:Test.Account_abv__c];
if(!Accnt.isEmpty()){
    Restrict = Accnt[0].Restricted_Products_vod__c ;
}
         List<Product_vod__c>  prd= [select ID , Name  from Product_vod__c where ID=:ProductID];
if(!prd.isEmpty()){
    Prodrestrict= prd[0].Name;
}
    if(Restrict.contains(Prodrestrict)) //This line throws error
         {
           ApexPages.Message Msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Selected Product is restricted for selected Account.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(Msg);
         }
```

Comment: What is Prodrestrict ? A variable ? What value does it contain ?

Comment: I'm guessing that `Restrict` is null. That's the only way you'd get that error. Try putting `System.assertNotEquals(null, Restrict);` on the line before to see if it fails.

Comment: I have edited with both are public strings with getter setters

Comment: Restricted_Products_vod__c may be null on Account

Comment: Add last if condition inside above if like this `if(!prd.isEmpty()){
    Prodrestrict= prd[0].Name;

    if(Restrict.contains(Prodrestrict)) //This line throws error
         {
           ApexPages.Message Msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Selected Product is restricted for selected Account.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(Msg);
         } }`

Comment: Have you instantiated Restrict? Its probably null. Can you do a debug to see what it contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a null check:

```
if (String.isNotBlank(Restrict) && Restrict.contains(ProdRestrict))
```

Comment: Now with your change I am getting this error.  Argument cannot be null.

Comment: Can you please suggest a wayout?

Comment: @SFDC_Learner is `ProdRestrict` also `null`?

Comment: Can you please help me here also?  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111227/email-send-from-apex-trigger